# csrf_exempt for class based views

Tags: python, django, django-views

Code:

```
class ErrorReportView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')
```

[image]

I use Postman, but I get

```
<p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `csrf_exempt` decorator should be applied to `"dispatch"` method. You can add the following decorator directly on top of your class, like so:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class ErrorReportView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')
```